# Specifying encryption when writing Spark 2 DataFrame to s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how to specify server side encryption when writing a Spark dataframe to S3 ? Specifically the line of code looks like this:

```
df.write.mode("append").parquet(file_path)
```

How do I specify that the file should be encrypted using say AES256 algorithm? Should I set a property when the SparkSession is created ? If so, what are the config values that should be set ?

Comment: `fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption=true` and `fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId=XXX` . Have a look at this [emr-plan-input-sse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-sse.html) .